# Reduce << operator chain in std::cout

Tags: c++, performance

Is there any way to reduce the chain of `<<` operator from the statements like following ?

```
std::cout << var1 << "!=" << var2;
```

`printf()` may be an option but anything else?

Because as the number of the operator `<<` increases so the running time too.

Is it possible to efficiently reduce the `<<` chain ?

Comment: you could write yourself a function called printf();

Comment: what "running time" are you after? If you need max throughput you usually dont print to stdout anyway...

Comment: I wanna disable stdin synchronization, so built-in printf is not acceptable.

Comment: Did you actually measure a difference between outputting more than once in a line versus constructing a string with the output and only outputting once? I'd love to see your profiling results.

Comment: You can't presume performance without measuring. What you are trying to accomplish may not actually help your performance.

Comment: Candidly, if you are concerned with the performance of the `<<` operator, `printf`, or any other standard functionality, you should already have the tools and know-how to measure performance across multiple libraries that offer similar functionality. At this point, I would ignore any perceived performance issues until they actually become **issues** for you. For now, just write code that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The fundamental reason is that `operator<<(const char*)` and `operator<<(int)` are both simple. In fact, they're so simple that they're likely to be inlined.

`printf(const char* format, ...)` on the other hand is a very complex function as it needs to deal with many possible format specifiers, and it also has a variable argument list that it needs to parse.

Any other single function would have the same disadvantage of being so complex it can't be inlined.